# QUERY returns 0

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a main data sheet (Main) with several columns, the relevant ones being column A, a date (displayed as dd.mm.YYYY) and column D, a numeric value. In a second sheet, I'm using the query function to build the sum over all these numeric values for a specific month using the following expression:

```
=SUM(QUERY(Main!$A$1:$D$2364; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = 1"; 1))
```

`MONTH(A)` returns a number between 0 and 11 and the above expression works perfectly well for January (0) to October (9). However, as soon as I try to compare `MONTH(A)`
with a number > 9, the sum shows zero despite there being numerous entries in both November and December.

What I get is this:

```
=SUM(QUERY(...; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = 10"; 1)) equals =SUM(QUERY(...; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = 1"; 1))
and
=SUM(QUERY(...; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = '10'"; 1)) equals 0
```

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the data (sheet) that you are working on, and if possibly, a reproducible spreadsheet containing your data and formula as it hard to simply know the real issue without the data backing it.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(Main!A2:D; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = 10"; 0)))
```

or:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(QUERY(Main!A2:D; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = 10"; 0)))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(Main!A2:D; "SELECT D WHERE MONTH(A) = 10"; 0)*1)))
```